# In an interview I didn't have any questions and they said to message them later if I did

Tags: interviewing

In an interview I was asked if I had any questions for the interviewer. I didn't have any and she said that if I thought of any questions later to text her.

Does this indicate that she is interested in hiring me? Should I ask questions directly?

Comment: *Always* prepare at least one question !

Comment: General Note: **don't ask questions just to ask questions because you've been told that you should**. Interviewers can easily identify "fake" questions. You *should* do your homework and prepare for the interview which almost always means that you'll have a few questions to ask.

Comment: To follow up on what others have said: if you prepared questions, but they were all already answered in the interview, then say so! It looks a lot better than either a) saying you don't have any questions or b) asking a lame fake question.

Answer (score 4):

## Does it mean anything?

Ultimately it doesn't mean much. It sounds like a standard way of ending an interview. However! I do think you should always have some questions prepared to ask the interviewer.

## Do your research!

This question is asked to gauge your potential interest in the company. It's always a good idea before an interview to research what you can about them. Typically I do this by looking at Glassdoor, Google and LinkedIn profiles of employees that I can find. As you do this you will inevitably discover some questions that you wish to ask and this is  the time to do so.

## ... but if you can't

Understandably that's not always realistic when the company is small or not much information can be found online. In these cases I defer to saying something along the lines of:

> Are there any concerns you have about my being able to do this role so
> I can address them with you now?

This will allow you to get some insight into areas that you may be able to tackle with the interviewer before the interview ends. Sometimes it will help to highlight when you genuinely aren't a good fit for the role and should consider other opportunities.

Answer (score 3):

It just means that if you think of questions you should contact the hiring officer, as opposed to anyone else you may have been in contact with during the process.  It does not convey in any way their level of interest in you but rather gives you a point of contact to follow up, that will be best able to handle your questions and queries.

Give it a few days then respond thanking her for taking time to interview you.

Answer (score 1):

**ALWAYS ask a question!** It indicates a deeper interest in the company. If your technical or task-related questions have already been answered, get personal: Ask "What was it that motivated you to join the company? What is it you like best about working here?" People like talking about themselves, their experiences and history with a place. It humanizes the conversation. If the answer is enthusiastic, you'll have a better idea of why you would want to work there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in a company, you should follow up with an email with some question. This tells them that you are interested. If you can't think of any question that won't sound lame or contrived, just send a note saying that you found the job or the company interesting and look forward to hearing from them. But an intelligent question is good, because it shows that you have really thought about the job, and are smart enough to understand what's going on.

For example, on my current job, while interviewing I said that I'd gotten the impression that the company got almost all its income from a couple of big clients, and had they considered what would happen if they lost one of those clients. I think this question showed that I had been paying attention during the interviews and that I understood the business implications of some of their decisions. And it wasn't an idle question: I wanted to know.